# alternative to gallery widget

Tags: android, gallery

Is there any faster alternative to Gallery widget in Android, because Gallery is so slow and lagging, i tryed to use view holder to reuse views, but without result. i used classic method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        ViewHolder holder;
         if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.image, null);

                // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
                // we want to bind data to.
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
         } else {
                // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
                // and the ImageView.
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
         holder.icon.setImageDrawable(getPicture(items[position]));
         return convertView;

         }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a couple of various galleries created by other and uploaded to [GitHub](https://github.com/search?langOverride=&language=Java&q=gallery&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories&x=14&y=19). You might need to checkout them to see how they are and how fast they are.

Comment: Where can i download the source code of Android Gallery version 1.3.1

Comment: @blessenm - Vervatovskis is referring to the Android Gallery widgit that can be re-used in applications to show items in a center-locked, horizontally scrolling list.  see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

Comment: @Vervatovskis - to browse the code of individual files, I find grepcode to be useful: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/widget/Gallery.java#Gallery

To download the whole open source android project, see: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html